# How to calculate cumsum based on row names stored as a list?

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I have a big data frame with the first column being alphanumeric row names. I use idx as below to pick random selection of rows for each column (here 3 rows). I now need to calculate cumulative sum for each idx[i,j]. My data frame is huge so functions in plyr package is preferred for the sake of computation time. Any idea how should I calculate that?

```
library(plyr)

V1 <- c('t14','t23','t54', 't13', 't1','t102', 't104', 't245')
V2 <- c(4.2, 5.3, 5.4,6, 7,8.5,9, 10.1)
V3 <- c(5.1, 5.1, 2.4,6.1, 7.7,5.5,1.99, 5.42)
my_df <- data.frame(V1, V2, V3)

 #The following line  randomly select 3 rows for each column
idx <- lapply(integer(ncol(my_df)-1), function(...) sample(my_df$V1, 3))
```

Thanks

Comment: "My data frame is huge so functions in plyr package is preferred for the sake of computation time" - that doesn't make sense. You use plyr for its simplicity and  ease of use, not because it's fast or scalable to huge datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, someone else could propose a `plyr` solution (I don't have much experience with this package). In the meantime, here is a `data.table` solution which may be just as fast (perhaps faster) as `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)

V1 <- c('t14','t23','t54', 't13', 't1','t102', 't104', 't245')
V2 <- c(4.2, 5.3, 5.4,6, 7,8.5,9, 10.1)
V3 <- c(5.1, 5.1, 2.4,6.1, 7.7,5.5,1.99, 5.42)
my_df <- data.frame(V1, V2, V3, stringsAsFactors = F)

#The following line  randomly select 3 rows for each column
set.seed(100) # Setting seed so that this example is reproducible
idx <- lapply(integer(ncol(my_df)-1), function(...) sample(my_df$V1, 3))

idx

# Additional code

# Import the data.table package - you'd want to move this line to the top of your code
library(data.table) 
setDT(my_df) # Cast the data.frame to data.table
setkey(my_df, V1) # Set the key for the data.table to V1

# With the key set as V1, I can just call idx[[i]] as the first argument of my_df 
# This will map each value of idx[[i]] to the appropriate row based on V1
# In the following, for the i-th vector in idx, I calculate the cumulative sum of each of V_{i + 1}
myResult = lapply(1:length(idx), function(i){
         my_df[idx[[i]], lapply(.SD, cumsum), .SDcols = i + 1]
    }
)
```

At this point, myResult is a list:

```
[[1]]
     V2
1:  5.4
2: 10.7
3: 16.7

[[2]]
     V3
1:  5.1
2: 11.2
3: 13.6
```

We create a data frame as follows:

```
# Column bind to create matrix of results
myResult = do.call(cbind, myResult)
```

The result is as follows:

```
     V2   V3
1:  5.4  5.1
2: 10.7 11.2
3: 16.7 13.6
```

Comment: Thanks @Jav for putting time and effort on this. I think I shouldn't convert idx to a vector since I need the idx to have two dimensions. As you might notice same row names have different values in different columns so the final output suppose to have cumulative sum for each column in separate columns. In the case of this example one column containing ('t54' , 't54'+'t23' , t54'+'t23' +'t13') for V2 and another column contain values of ("t14",  "t14"+"t13" , "t14"+"t13"+"t54")  for column V3.

Comment: My apologies, I have corrected mainly the last line of code to reflect the cumulative sum. I have also left idx as a list. Let me know if the output above is what you expect.

Comment: Also, if this needs to be generalized for a larger number of columns, let me know and I can edit the above accordingly.

Comment: I think V1 should not appear on the final output since idx may pick 3 different rows for each column. Given that the out put should be a single data frame with V2 being (5.4 , 10.7, 16.7) and V3 being (5.1, 11.2, 13.6) for the above example.

Comment: I see. Please see my edit above. The line `my_df[idx[[i]], lapply(.SD, cumsum), .SDcols = i + 1]` grabs the rows given by the i-th vector of idx, and applies the cumulative sum to the (i+1)-th column of your data.frame.

Comment: *"data.table solution which may be just as fast (perhaps faster) as `plyr`"*, lol, yes. `data.table` may be as fast as `plyr` like a carbon fiber racing bike may be as fast as a [big wheel](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS519US519&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=big%20wheel).